# Traits vs. abstract classes for code reuse

Tags: php, oop, interface, class-hierarchy

While working on a project i stumbled across a question relating to the proper way of choosing the correct form of code reuse in terms of traits vs. abstract base classes. I came across the point where i have multiple abstract base classes but can only inherit from one due multiple inheritance restrictions from PHP. Rethinking this makes me questioning my design and so i want to know how others would solve this problem.

**Following scenario**

In my project i have two kind of calculations

1. Simple calculations
2. Grouped calculations which in case are simple calculations just with some more information

**Setting up the interfaces**

```
interface SimpleResultInterface{
    public function getValue();
}

interface GroupedResultInterface extends SimpleResultInterface {
    public function getGroupValues();
}
```

**Setting up the base classes**

Avoiding code duplication as a good form of design i set up two abstract base classes.

```
abstract class SimpleResultBase implements SimpleResultInterface{

    public function getValue(){
        return 1;
    }
}

abstract class GroupedResultBase extends SimpleResultBase implements  GroupedResultInterface {

    public function getGroupValues(){
        return array(
            "group1" => 1,
            "group2" => 2,
            "group3" => 3,
        );
    }
}
```

So the first question here is

1. Does **GroupedResultBase** need to inherit **SimpleResultBase** in terms of expressing the interface relationship from **SimpleResultInterface** and **GroupedResultInterface** ?

I have chosen yes because otherwise i would have to duplicate the **getValue** method from **SimpleResultBase**

**What we have so far**

Now i can epxpress

1. **GroupedResultInterface** *instanceof* **SimpleResultInterface** ( true )
2. **GroupedResultBase** *instanceof* **SimpleResultBase** ( true )
3. **SimpleResultBase** *instanceof* **SimpleResultInterface** ( true )
4. **GroupedResultBase** *instanceof* **GroupedResultInterface** ( true )

**Going concrete where the troubles start**

At this point there are no concrete classes. Now i want to make two concrete classes which have a relationship together respecting the interface definitons.

```
class OEESimpleResult extends SimpleResultBase {

}

class OEEGroupedResult extends GroupedResultBase{

}
```

this works very nicely but what i can't do is this

```
class OEESimpleResult extends SimpleResultBase {

}

class OEEGroupedResult extends OEESimpleResult,GroupedResultBase {

}
```

> interface GroupedResultInterface extends SimpleResultInterface
>
> As above noted in the interface definiton. Each grouped result is also
>   a simple result. So i would have expected that **OEEGroupedResult** also is a **OEESimpleResult**

But when i would do this i can not reuse my abstract base class **GroupedResultBase** because multiple inheritance is not allowed. This leads me to following questions.

1. It seems that the class relationship in the abstract classes freezes the inheritance chain down the road. Would it be better to remove the abstract classes and replace them with traits making the concrete classes using them?
2. What is the right way of providing default implementations if u have multiple interfaces but can only inherit from one base class?
3. This problem seems very common in oop so are there any best practices and recommendations how to overcome this issue?
4. Should classes that implement the interfaces also express the relationship in form of inheritance like on the interface level or is the interface realtionship alone  enough? In my case should **OEEGroupedResult** express the relation to **OEESimpleResult** on the class level like their interfaces on the interface level.

Thank u for your help :)

Comment: Could you reply, as your question is really one to debate. My answer is not the only approach, so we could just improve it. But ignoring it is not the best decision if you want to get answer of course.

Comment: Its not the only approach but your answer led me to the correct solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are working in oop style, you might hear about SOLID principles. 
So your design breaks the following letters S,I,D with potential to break O and L.

So how do you broke **"S"**:
Right here!

```
class OEEGroupedResult extends OEESimpleResult,GroupedResultBase {

}
```

Suddenly or luckily php doesn't allow it, but your class would provide some additional separate logic, so you will have at least two reasons to change it. But yeah, it's because of

```
interface GroupedResultInterface extends SimpleResultInterface {
    public function getGroupValues();
}
```

Here's your **I** letter breaks. Solution is pretty simple: think about methods your GroupedResultInterface really needs and put it inside and **really** means that these methods must do the same job. They are not as you are breaking letter **D** here:

```
abstract class SimpleResultBase implements SimpleResultInterface{

    public function getValue(){
        return 1;
    }
}

abstract class GroupedResultBase extends SimpleResultBase implements  GroupedResultInterface {

    public function getGroupValues(){
        return array(
            "group1" => 1,
            "group2" => 2,
            "group3" => 3,
        );
    }
}
```

Your class `class GroupedResultBase` depends on concrete method of another class. But you will quickly fix it after interface segregation.

**Notice**. I'm using traits when I can't change something inside vendor classes. Only. It's just me, but when I think that trait will help me then something is wrong with architecture. It's up to you of course.

Little link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Have fun!